# sudo: grub-setup: command not found

Tags: 13.04

I'm installing windows along with Ubuntu 13. At some point I have to say:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc
sudo grub-setup /dev/sda     # NOTE THAT THERE IS NO DIGIT
sudo umount /boot
```

However, the second line says that `sudo: grub-setup: command not found`, although the previous one said `grub-pc is already the newest version.`

`man grub-setup` is working well.

Comment: where did you get these instructions, could you post the URL? they seem wrong, I think you should use `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. The "no digit" part is OK, as you want to install grub in the drive's MBR, not in a specific partition.

Comment: @roadmr http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: Well, it should be `grub-install`, I edited that answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grub-setup` is no longer used, it was replaced by `grub-install`. I've edited that other answer to use `grub-install`.